# How can I create a an application with a navigation bar and three detail views?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

How can I create an iPad application that has a navigation bar containing three views?  Is there a simple tutorial I could refer to for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's a tutorial specifically for creating a navigation-based application with exactly three views for iPad, but reading [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) will tell you everything you need to know about setting up a navigation-based app. How many views you want your app to have, and what you put in them, is where your creativity comes in.